# Is declaring a string full of "$" bad practice?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I'm doing a project for university and found myself in a situation where it would be useful to define a string with all $ as their starting values.

This serves to illustrate a similar situation:

```
string DB 22 dup('$') ; I declare the string with dollar signs
; Input to string
lea dx, string
mov ah, 0Ah
int 21h                     
mov bx, dx
mov ah, 0
mov al, ds:[bx+1]
```

Then if I print the string it will end in the correct character, without needing to add a '$' at the end manually.

I'm in a situation where it's infinitely easier to do it this way but I'm afraid the teacher might point out this is bad practice, or present an argument against it. I don't really want to face that sort of situation just for being practical. Are there any reason this is bad practice?

Comment: No more so than initializing a C `char*` allocation with NULs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... it's only going to be useful if you're printing the string with `int 21h/9`. If you were using it as a filename to open, for example, you'd want it terminated with zero.

For `int21h/0Ah`, the first byte is "maximum length" to input. But '$' would allow more input than you've got buffer to hold it. I'd consider that "bad practice"! After the interrupt returns (user has hit "enter"), the second byte is the actual length entered. As I recall, this includes the CR (13 decimal or 0Dh hex), and dos always puts the CR there. (Linux does it differently, which can cause a problem, actually). The actual text input starts at `string + 2` (which you seem to have figured out). If you were to start printing (with `int 21h/9`) at `string` dos would probably see your first "$" as "end of string" and print nothing. (Try it! I'd have to reboot to try dos.)

Whether your teacher would consider it "bad practice" would depend on your teacher. Like CPUs, OSes, and assemblers... they're not all the same! :)